Securing Swagger UI endpoints in Spring Boot via OIDC and Keycloak
I want to secure my endpoints in a Spring-Boot-generated Swagger UI via Keycloak and OIDC.
I've created an OpenApiConfiguration, which contains the following code:
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components()
                    .addSecuritySchemes("open-id",
                        new SecurityScheme()
                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.OPENIDCONNECT)
                                .openIdConnectUrl("https://doma.in/auth/realms/realm/.well-known/openid-configuration")
                    )
            )
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("open-id"))
}

In the Controller I've added these security requirements:
@SecurityRequirements({ @SecurityRequirement(name = "open-id") })

When I click on the lock to authorize at the described endpoint, the Available authorizations dialog opens with multiple options:

open-id (OAuth2, authorization_code)
open-id (OAuth2, implicit)
open-id (OAuth2, refresh_token)
open-id (OAuth2, password)
open-id (OAuth2, client_credentials)
...

When I click on 'refresh_token', I get redirected to the Keycloak and receive the error message 'Client not found' and in the URL the client_id query is empty.
How can I add the client ID to the spring boot code?

Please clarify the question. Do you want to secure the swagger endpoints so that the SwaggerUI is only available when authenticated and authorized or do you want to add the possibility to use the SwaggerUI to make authenticated requests to your API?

Refresh token is to ... refresh ... tokens an OAuth2 client got beforehand with authorization code flow. We have no information about your Spring application. Is it configured with oauth2Login or oauth2ResourceServer? What are dependencies and application properties? Your question also lacks information about declared clients in your Keycloak realm.

@ch4mp, sorry for being unclear. refresh_token as the selected option was just an example, the same is valid for all other options as well.

If you want your question to be clear - and get a chance to be answered - edit it to add the elements I listed. It currently isn't a good question and should be closed.
